# AddAccessRule: "Some or all identity references could not be translated." How can I check a specific server?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, acl

With most `ActiveDirectory` commands, you can add a parameter: `-server`. This parameter has proven to be extremely useful to me, since where I am working seems to have some kind of slow updating system, and when I don't only use one of the servers, my programs can lag and completely bug.

I'm also trying to modify the ACL of a folder. To do this, I have a function that takes the `-PassThru` of a `New-ADGroup` command, and then pipes this into a custom function.

The custom function creates and returns new `AccessRules` (which are added to array `$AccessRules`), which are then added to an `$acl` variable:

```
$AccessRules | 
%{$acl.AddAccessRule($_)}
```

This inconsistently returns errors: Sometimes, it runs smoothly, but other times, it returns the classic "Some or all identity references could not be translated". I am 90% sure this comes from the fact that it is not checking the right server, because even between

```
Get-ADGroup -filter {name -eq "[group name]"}
```

and

```
Get-ADGroup -filter {name -eq "[group name]"} -Server [server name/address]
```

I only get results for the second.

Is there a way I could add a similar `-Server` Parameter to something like `.AddAccessRule()`? Perhaps a slightly different method?

Comment: Just to reinforce the point: In debug mode, if I wait until the `Get-ADGroup` command *without* `-Server` works, and then finish the script, then everything works fine. It really is a matter of the servers updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a neat trick specified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30256574/1627055). You create a `New-PSDrive` to your AD using a certain server, then you call `cd` or `set-location` to that drive, voila, any .NET functions called (and any cmdlets that are not otherwise redirected to a different server) will use that server to process the requests, resolve AD entities into SIDs, etc, without you waiting for AD replication.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't actually seem to work. At least for the .NET functions. Any tips?

Comment: Well, I wonder do you use .NET function to assign ACL to a *remote* resource? If yes, then it shouldn't, and you'd better first create groups, then kick AD replication, and only then run script to assign rights to those groups.